# lebesgue integral on general measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Is there a way to compute the Lebesgue integral of certain function over general measurable set $A$, for example $\int_A x\;\mbox{d}\mu$ ?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: There is indeed! $\int_A x d\mu = \int_{\mathbb R} x \chi_A d\mu$, where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of $A \subset \mathbb R$. Do you know the definition of $\int_{\mathbb R} x \chi_A d\mu$?

Comment: From university, I only remember that the integral is defined by limit of integrals of simple functions.

Comment: Yes. Is this not sufficient?

Comment: There are other ways of computing integrals, e.g. approximating the integrand by nicer things and using monotone convergence or dominated convergence. But in general, computing integrals is hard work! Integration was hard work even at high school!